# How do I make my PHP login script secure from SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, security, authentication

I have this PHP login code (that I borrowed from another question on here) - I am easily able to hack it with SQL injection and would like to make it more secure - bit of a newbie to development and would like some assistance! How do I stop these kind of attacks?
Thank you!

```
$userinfo = array(
                'user1'=>'password1',
                'user2'=>'password2'
                );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    }else {
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
            <p>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['username']?></p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no database in this code, and hence no SQL. SQL injection specifically applies to databases.

Comment: Phrase "SQL injection" assumes having some SQL

Comment: Also, how are you easily hacking it? What input are you using?

Comment: If I enter 1=1 into the username input box it allows me access

Comment: well it does! can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Some hint questions for the code above

What does this return, if you have something in `$_POST['username']` that is not a key in the array?

```
$userinfo[$_POST['username']]
```

What does this return, if you don't specify any password in the POST request?

```
$_POST['password']
```

Hint: they are the same, whatever they are...

And to clarify: this is **not** SQL injection. Just plain exploiting a dumb program.

Comment: it just returns you to login - as if you'd just pressed a button that doesn't do anything